# ios/objective-c:configureCellAtIndexPath: places image in wrong place

Tags: ios, cell

I have a tableview that populates cells using `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  However, when a row is changed, the delegate method calls `configureCellAtIndexPath`, presumably, in order to to change just one cell.

When I change the photo for the cell, instead of placing it in the correct position on the far left of the table row, `configureCellAtIndexPath` puts it on the right hand side and also does not crop it correctly.  When the user scrolls up or down, the image corrects, presumably because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is setting things straight.

My question is why is `configureCellatIndexPath` placing photo in wrong place?

Here's a visual on the problem:
 [image]

Here is my code (which may include some redundancy, but is the same for both `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `configureCell`):

```
cell.imageView.image = chosenImage;
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
[cell.imageView.image drawInRect:imageRect];
cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=20.0;
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 500, 50);
```

Comment: Why set the imageView frame in configureCell? Is it different?

Comment: no. The image is new but the formatting is the same.  I will try commenting the frame reference out.

Comment: Strangely enough that seemed to fix problem.  Thanks!